# What exactly are bulletproofs replacing in monero?

Tags: ringct, ring-signatures, confidential-transactions, range-proofs

I am stuck on these questions in understanding bulletproofs:

Are bulletproofs a way to hide the sender and the amount?

What is the difference between bulletproofs, RingCT and Ring signatures?

Edit:

Confidential txs just hide the amount.

RingCT is based upon this, but also hides the sender using stealth address, ring signatures and range/bullet proofs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bulletproofs are used to prove that the amounts in confidential transactions are in range, so you can't do underhanded things like creating negative amounts. They replace Borromean range proofs. They are smaller in size, and faster to verify, though slower to generate. As used in Monero, they are unrelated to ring signatures, but are part of RingCT, since RingCT uses confidential transactions, and thus range proofs.

Amounts are hidden by Pedersen commitments.

Senders are hidden by ring signatures.

Recipients are hidden by stealth addresses.